# defaultwebpage.cgi and no index.html

Tags: php, linux

I have new server, server ip point me to

`http://ip-address/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi`

File manager can show me public_html folder without any index.html and htdocs? Please advise me how to run php file by removing defaultwebpage.cgi?

Directory structure (from comment below):
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have a look for the server config e.g. `apache.conf`, `vhost.conf` or `.htaccess` files.

One of them will contain a redirect command.

Comment: <a href="http://tinypic.com?ref=2hrjvy0" target="_blank"><img src="http://i43.tinypic.com/2hrjvy0.jpg" border="0" alt="Image and video hosting by TinyPic"></a>

Comment: I cannot see apache.conf, vhost.conf or .htaccess files. Please see above image

Comment: I can see .htaccess, please guide me how to fix redirect. I can see .htaccess in almost all folders, in root and in sub-folders too.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you are having a **linux hosting**. Normally in linux hosting the files has to be uploaded into the **public_html** folder where as in windows hosting you use the **htdocs** folder. Just upload your **index file** to the **public_html** folder and access your site it will automatically load the index file.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by adding this PHP configuration on your htaccess

```
<IfModule mime_module>
AddType application/x-httpd-ea-php56 .php .php5 .phtml
</IfModule>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|images|robots\.txt|css)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```